# Updating Log-out record not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a log-out system, which will record users when they logged out. But it's not updating properly.

Code:

```
<?php
include('global.php');
        $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and 
        password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

        {
    $logintime=$row['logintime'];
    }


        if(mysql_num_rows($result))
        {

        $query = "UPDATE time_tb SET ";


            $query = $query."logoutime='".$p_time."' ";

            $query = $query."WHERE logintime='".$logintime."'"; 

            ExecuteQuery($query);




session_destroy();
header ("location: loginadmin.php");
            }
?>
```

Comment: Please dont use the `mysql_` database extension, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Why bother setting `$_SESSION` if you are logging them out? What is `$p_time`? What data type is `logoutime`? Are there any errors? You also may be open to SQL injections depending on how those initial values are set..

Comment: where are the variables `$tbl_name`, `$myusername`, and `$mypassword` coming from? are they all set in `global.php`?

Comment: @chris85, i have already made a global variable p_time which is time.

Comment: yes. they already set in global php

Comment: you need a semicolon `;` after `header("location: loginadmin.php")`

Comment: add backticks around ``$tbl_name``

Comment: i believe `mysql_num_rows` will only output the number of rows in your result, not the actual rows. Youre going to need a `while` loop to fetch your results

Comment: Im a bit confused in your flow. It seems that your `$tbl_name` already has a column that tracks updated times in `logintime` How is that column updated? Why not update that table and the `time_tb` table at the same time?

Comment: why are you setting your `$_SESSION` variables, if you will destroy them `session_destroy()` right after?

Comment: @CodeGodie why will the query be wrong?

Comment: @chris85 it gets overwritten per each line.

Comment: i have already made a debug still not working. please see above code

Comment: @CodeGodie `$query = $query.` shouldn't be overwritten, should be appended.

Comment: @chris85 you are right, I was looking for the short way `.=` but that concatenation does work as well. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What is `ExecuteQuery`? Do you have anything in your error logs? Are you checking error logs?

Comment: ..so problem solved?

Comment: they are no errors, but it is not updating on the table. i just need to update the logoutime row but its not.

Comment: @chris85, still not updating

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? What does `its working to me` mean?

Comment: i mean the query=$query. work well , but the problem is my table is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $query = "UPDATE time_tb SET ";
 $query.="logoutime=".$p_time." WHERE logintime=".$logintime;
```

And yes you should check your sql query in console by using `print_r` or others in your code.